# Make public site with wamp

Tags: windows, php

I wrote simple site and I access by typing http://localhost/test/index.php on mu local machine. I use wamp.Can somebody over net access this site, I need to show ? How to set my default page to be home.php?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://checkmyip.com to see your IP addess.. Go to http://{your-ip-here} to see if your site is accessible.

```
How to set my default page to be home.php?
```

Answer (score 1):

Register (for free) at http://www.dyndns.com/, choose a hostname and install their client software to run on your server.

If you are connected to the internet thru a router that does NAT (Network Address Translation) make sure your PC has a static IP address (instead of DHCP-assigned) and configure the router to pass any incoming connection on port 80 to that IP address.

Set up any firewall you have running to allow incoming connections on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your default index page in the apache httpd.conf file. From the WAMP config panel, select Config files › httpd.conf. Then search for the line that looks like

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.html default.htm
```

Apache selects directory index files according to this left, with order preference from left to right. So you'd want to change this line to

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```